# Parsec does not recognize block comments

Tags: haskell, mustache, parsec

I have a problem with Parsec recognizing comments when parsing mustache templates.
The various mustache tags all start with `{{` include the block comment (`{{!comment}}`).
I have set commentStart and commentEnd to `{{!` and `}}` in my TokenParser.
Whenever I add comments to a template, Parsec complains that the comment is unexpected.
It expects a mustache variable instead, since that is the only token that matches `{{`.

When does Parsec remove comments? I thought it would happen before the source hits my parser?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant portion of your parsing code?

Comment: You might be interested in looking at the Parsec parser for mustache I have in the `mustache2hs` package.

Comment: mustache2hs is quite a cool idea!
I took a look at it, it could benefit from some modularization :-).
My parser builds an XML/mustache AST to do some DOM stuff, so your parser is not really applicable to my situation (its already coded anyways...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parsec doesn't remove comments. In a `TokenParser`, comments are subsumed under white space, so

```
whiteSpace tokenParser
```

skips comments and ordinary white space (blanks, tabs, newlines, ...).

Usually, you use `lexeme parser` to skip all white space following a lexeme, then you only need one initial white-space-skipping for the top-level parser to skip any leading white space in the source, afterward, all white space (including comments) is handled automatically (by the `TokenParser` that `makeTokenParser` creates).

If you don't use `lexeme` and handle white space manually, you must take care of tokens/lexemes that are a prefix of the comment delimiter. If you try the prefix first, that will succeed, but only consume part of the comment delimiter, in this case leaving the `'!'` for the variable parser, which then fails.

Comment: oooh, of course! I have some "significant white space" stuff, which is why I often simply use the Char.string parser. When I put comments between XML attributes (where I use a lexeme parser) it actually works. Thanks!

Comment: This also happens to be a solution for Parsec problem where comments or whitespace at the beginning of the input are not ignored.